# Starting program in C# including all files

Tags: c#, process

I'm having problems running a process from my program.

When I start the process it says "Cannot find Tibia.dat!" ( it thinks the exe file is located in project directory, when it isn't ).

So when I start the process in my program ( from: C:\program\Tibia\Tibia.exe ) it says "Cannot find C:\user\marcus\my documents\visual studio 2009\blablalba\Tibia.dat".

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Process.Start(addressToFirstTibia + "\\Tibia.exe");
```

Grateful for help !!

Comment: Can you post the code that try to access to `Tibia.dat`?

Comment: I don't have the code, because it's not my game I'm trying to start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the working directory. Tibia.exe probably expects it to be the same as the executable's directory, so try:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName         = Path.Combine(addressToFirstTibia, "Tibia.exe"), 
    WorkingDirectory = addressToFirstTibia 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is Tibia.exe looking for Tibia.dat internally?  It may be detecting somehow that the "current working directory" is the project directory, not its own executable directory.

There's a property called `WorkingDirectory` on `ProcessStartInfo` that may solve this issue for you.  Info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx).